# iis 7.5 rewrite to friendly url issues

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, url-rewriting

I'm migrating from apache to iis and i'm facing issues with url rewriting.

i want all requests like this:

```
http://192.168.0.44/aaa/bbb/ccc/testword
```

to query this not-friendly url:

```
http://192.168.0.44/aaa/bbb/ccc/index.php?word=testword
```

so my web.config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^192\.168\.0\.44/aaa/bbb/ccc/([^/]+)/?$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="192.168.0.44/aaa/bbb/ccc/index.php?word={R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

but when i visit such a url, i get a 404 not found error. details:

```
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    MapRequestHandler
Handler StaticFile
Error Code  0x80070002

Requested URL   http://192.168.0.44:80/aaa/bbb/ccc/testword
Physical Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aaa\bbb\ccc\testword
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User  Anonymous
```

what am i doing wrong ?

p.s. there will be a domain there instead of that ip, it's just that i want to test it locally first before i do it live.

the rewrite module 2 is installed. i can see in the iis manager gui.

thanks in advance.

Comment: please close, it's solved

Comment: It's even better if you can post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted this rewrite rule which was at the top level and implemented it in it's simplest way ( without the long path and the IP ) in the deepest folder ( ccc ). It automagically worked.